# Error when using packages in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am working on an assignment that requires us to use a package for our java files. I followed a previous post that had an explanation but unfortunately I keep running into this error. I attached an image since I am not entirely sure how to describe it. Thank you for all your help in advanced. I am using version 1.66.0

[project in visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Vww.png)

Comment: Is it because of a missing semicolon (;) at the end of line 1?

Comment: @qrsngky Yes you are right! Huge oversight by me. i am not sure if you can answer this question but is it normal for it to flag this as well "Fraction.java is a non-project file, only JDK classes are added to its build path" Thank you!